# Assigning value inside a pandas group

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have this large dataframe where I report the first eighth rows:

```
Genes   Sub-Gene    Type    Reference       TrueType
1       SG1         type3       0           NothingYet
1       SG1         type1       1           NothingYet
1       SG2         type7       0           NothingYet
1       SG2         type3       0           NothingYet
1       SG2         type9       0           NothingYet
1       SG2         type9       1           NothingYet
2       SG1         type3       1           NothingYet
2       SG1         type7       0           NothingYet
```

What I want, for each Sub-Gene,  is to set "NothingYet" to the value of "Type" for which "Reference" is 1.

What I expect is :

```
Genes   Sub-Gene    Type    Reference       TrueType
1       SG1         type3       0           type1
1       SG1         type1       1           type1
1       SG2         type7       0           type9
1       SG2         type3       0           type9
1       SG2         type9       0           type9
1       SG2         type9       1           type9
2       SG1         type3       1           type3
2       SG1         type7       0           type3
```

So far, here is what I have.

```
grouped = data.groupby(['Genes', 'Sub-Gene'])
for name, group in grouped:
    group['TrueType'] = group.ix[group.Reference.idxmax(),'Type']
```

Of course, that doesn't work because you can't change values with only `group['TrueType']`. I tried `group.ix['TrueType']`, but I get an error. Any idea?

Comment: You can get the groups values with command ``data.groupby(['Genes','Sub-Gene']).apply(lambda x:(x[x['Reference']==1])['Type'])``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO we should make this easier than it is right now.  What I often do is sort so that I can use `transform` + `iloc` to pick out the appropriate value, something like

```
grouped = df.sort("Reference").groupby(["Genes", "Sub-Gene"])
df["TrueType"] = grouped["Type"].transform(lambda x: x.iloc[-1])
```

For example:

```
In [211]: df
Out[211]: 
   Genes Sub-Gene   Type  Reference    TrueType
0      1      SG1  type3          0  NothingYet
1      1      SG1  type1          1  NothingYet
2      1      SG2  type7          0  NothingYet
3      1      SG2  type3          0  NothingYet
4      1      SG2  type9          0  NothingYet
5      1      SG2  type9          1  NothingYet
6      2      SG1  type3          1  NothingYet
7      2      SG1  type7          0  NothingYet

[8 rows x 5 columns]

In [212]: df.sort("Reference").groupby(["Genes", "Sub-Gene"])["Type"].transform(lambda x: x.iloc[-1])
Out[212]: 
0    type1
2    type9
3    type9
4    type9
7    type3
1    type1
5    type9
6    type3
Name: Type, dtype: object
```

producing

```
In [213]: df["TrueType"] = df.sort("Reference").groupby(["Genes", "Sub-Gene"])["Type"].transform(lambda x: x.iloc[-1])

In [214]: df
Out[214]: 
   Genes Sub-Gene   Type  Reference TrueType
0      1      SG1  type3          0    type1
1      1      SG1  type1          1    type1
2      1      SG2  type7          0    type9
3      1      SG2  type3          0    type9
4      1      SG2  type9          0    type9
5      1      SG2  type9          1    type9
6      2      SG1  type3          1    type3
7      2      SG1  type7          0    type3

[8 rows x 5 columns]
```

Comment: Thanks! Fast and efficient :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I would do

```
import pandas as pd
from StringIO import StringIO
strDf = """Genes,Sub-Gene,Type,Reference
1,SG1,type3,0
1,SG1,type1,1
1,SG2,type7,0
1,SG2,type3,0
1,SG2,type9,0
1,SG2,type9,1
2,SG1,type3,1
2,SG1,type7,0"""
data = pd.read_csv(StringIO(strDf))

pp = data.groupby(['Genes','Sub-Gene']).apply(lambda x:(x[x['Reference']==1])['Type'])
for k,v in pp.iterkv():
    data.loc[(data['Genes']==k[0]) & (data['Sub-Gene']==k[1]),'TrueType']=v
```

Resulting in

```
   Genes Sub-Gene   Type  Reference TrueType
0      1      SG1  type3          0    type1
1      1      SG1  type1          1    type1
2      1      SG2  type7          0    type9
3      1      SG2  type3          0    type9
4      1      SG2  type9          0    type9
5      1      SG2  type9          1    type9
6      2      SG1  type3          1    type3
7      2      SG1  type7          0    type3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `update` a series after fetching the desired `TrueType`. Note that I set index `Genes` and `Sub-Gene`. You can `reset_index` afterwards if you don't want it.

```
In [146]: data = pd.read_csv (StringIO ('''Genes   Sub-Gene    Type    Reference       TrueType
1       SG1         type3       0           NothingYet
1       SG1         type1       1           NothingYet
1       SG2         type7       0           NothingYet
1       SG2         type3       0           NothingYet
1       SG2         type9       0           NothingYet
1       SG2         type9       1           NothingYet
2       SG1         type3       1           NothingYet
2       SG1         type7       0           NothingYet'''),sep='\s+')

In [147]: data.set_index(['Genes','Sub-Gene'],inplace=True)

In [148]: data.TrueType.update (data.ix[data.Reference == 1,'Type'])

In [149]: data
Out[149]: 
                 Type  Reference TrueType
Genes Sub-Gene                           
1     SG1       type3          0    type1
      SG1       type1          1    type1
      SG2       type7          0    type9
      SG2       type3          0    type9
      SG2       type9          0    type9
      SG2       type9          1    type9
2     SG1       type3          1    type3
      SG1       type7          0    type3

[8 rows x 3 columns]
```

Answer (score 0):

In spirit of DSM's answer, I'll just post what I would have done - just so you see the alternatives possible.

```
df.set_index(['Genes', 'Sub-Gene'], inplace=True)
df['TrueType'] = df.groupby(level=[0,1]).apply(lambda x: x.sort('Reference', ascending=False).iloc[0]['Type'])
```